# Meaning of different elements of delivered json-Data-Structure when geocoding with Python and OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geocoding

I'm trying to do some geocoding in Python with the library geocoder and OpenStreetMap:

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.osm('11 Wall Street, New York')
print(g.json)
```

Where can I get information about the different elements of the json-Dictionary?

The json-Dictionary:

```
{
   'accuracy': 0.511,
   'address': 'New York Stock Exchange, 11, Wall Street, Financial District, Manhattan, New York County, New York, 10005, United States',
   'bbox': {
       'northeast': [40.7073927, -74.0108331],
       'southwest': [40.7066568, -74.0115875]
   },
   'city': 'New York',
   'confidence': 10,
   'country': 'United States',
   'country_code': 'us',
   'county': 'New York County',
   'housenumber': '11',
   'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_point_of_interest.p.20.png',
   'importance': 0.511,
   'lat': 40.7070653,
   'lng': -74.01117438284459,
   'neighborhood': 'Financial District',
   'ok': True,
   'osm_id': 278053530,
   'osm_type': 'way',
   'place_id': 158065100,
   'place_rank': 30,
   'postal': '10005',
   'quality': 'attraction',
   'raw': {
       'place_id': 158065100,
       'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
       'osm_type': 'way',
       'osm_id': 278053530,
       'boundingbox': ['40.7066568', '40.7073927', '-74.0115875', '-74.0108331'],
       'lat': '40.7070653',
       'lon': '-74.01117438284459',
       'display_name': 'New York Stock Exchange, 11, Wall Street, Financial District, Manhattan, New York County, New York, 10005, United States',
       'place_rank': 30,
       'category': 'tourism',
       'type': 'attraction',
       'importance': 0.511,
       'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_point_of_interest.p.20.png',
       'address': {
           'tourism': 'New York Stock Exchange',
           'house_number': '11',
           'road': 'Wall Street',
           'neighbourhood': 'Financial District',
           'suburb': 'Manhattan',
           'county': 'New York County',
           'city': 'New York',
           'state': 'New York',
           'postcode': '10005',
           'country': 'United States',
           'country_code': 'us'
       }
   },
   'region': 'New York',
   'state': 'New York',
   'status': 'OK',
   'street': 'Wall Street',
   'suburb': 'Manhattan',
   'type': 'attraction'
```

}

Some elements are of course obviously clear like lat and lng.
What does a value of 0.511  for accuracy  mean?
What's the meaning of ok?
What does a value of 10 for confidence mean?
So for short: where can I get more info on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, these aren't all documented.

- accuracy is an alias for "importance".  There is some commentary on how importance is calculated in the osm-search/wikipedia-wikidata [readme](https://github.com/osm-search/wikipedia-wikidata)

> Nominatim can use the page ranking of Wikipedia pages to help indicate the relative importance of osm features. This is done by calculating an importance score between 0 and 1 based on the number of inlinks to an article for a location. If two places have the same name and one is more important than the other, the wikipedia score often points to the correct place.

- ok is true if both lat and lng are truthy.  https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/39b9999ec70e61da9fa52fe9fe82a261ad70fa8b/geocoder/base.py#L129
- confidence is documented here: [confidence](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/39b9999ec70e61da9fa52fe9fe82a261ad70fa8b/docs/features/Confidence%20Score.md)